# Lodash Update Collection Where

Tags: javascript, lodash

Say you have a collection like this:

```
var sizes = [
 {label: 'Small', instock: true, onsale: true},
 {label: 'Medium', instock: false, onsale: true},
 {label: 'Large', instock: false, onsale: true},
];
```

Note that the collection here is really simple for the purposes of the question, but in the real use-case the objects could be much larger and more complicated and re-iterated several times (so the solution for this needs to be as efficient as possible).

I need to update the stock of everything that's not in stock to true.  Here is what I tried so far:

```
var index = _.findIndex(sizes, instock:false);
sizes[index].instock = true;
```

But it only updates 1 of the items, in MySQL you could do something like this in 1 line of code and I want to try and figure out how to do something similar in Lodash or Plain Javascript (with 1 function or 1 line of code) because I have to do stuff like this rather frequently and it's becoming extremely cumbersome in plain javascript to do it with a loop manually iterating over the entire collection.

The MySQL equivalent would be something like:

```
UPDATE sizes instock=true WHERE instock=false
```

I want to do something similar in Lodash or Plain Javascript, whatever is easiest and most efficient.

Another thing I'm trying to figure out how to do is this MySQL equivalent.

```
UPDATE sizes onsale=false WHERE onsale=true AND instock=false
```

Comment: All libraries will effectively be looping over the collection.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set the `instock` of every object to true you can use a simple for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++){
    sizes[i].instock = true;
}
```

or with lodash (which is going to be effectively the same)

```
_.each(sizes, function (size){size.instock = true});
```

Note that we are not checking the value of `instock` here because it doesn't matter. If `instock` is `true`, it will remain the same, and if it is false it will change. Checking for the value of `unstuck` costs more than 'unnecessarily' assigning `true` to a value that is already true.

For your second statement, we do actually need to check the value of `instock`, but not onsale, like we didn't check the value of instock in the first statement.

```
_.each(sizes, function (size){
    if(!instock) {
        size.onsale = false;
    }
});
```

*Important: I am assuming that the values of the variable that I didn't check are never null/undefined. If they can be and in that case shouldn't be changed, then you do still need to add checks.*

Answer (score 1):

The more perfomant way to solve your problem would be using a plain `for` loop.

You could have a helper function to go over the elements of the array. This helper function could receive a function as an argument that would do the check in order to update the key of the object with the proper value. This way, it could be emulated (in a very simple manner) the SQL update statement.

```js
var sizes = [{
  label: 'Small',
  instock: true,
  onsale: true
}, {
  label: 'Medium',
  instock: false,
  onsale: true
}, {
  label: 'Large',
  instock: false,
  onsale: true
}, ];

function update(arr, key, transformFnc) {
  var i = arr.length,
    obj;
  for (; i !== 0;) {
    obj = arr[--i];
    obj[key] = transformFnc(obj);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(update(sizes, 'instock', function(obj) {
  // Returns true when instock is false -> is the same as putting all to true.
  return true;
}));
console.log(update(sizes, 'onsale', function(obj) {
  // Returns false when onsale=true AND instock=false, otherwise, doesn't do anything
  return obj.onsale === true && obj.instock === false ? false : obj.onsale;
}));
```

Hope it helps.